# How to format numbers in Excel column using the same exponent?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a bunch of decimal numbers in a particular column, for example:

```
1.123E-05
4.567E-06
8.910E-03
1.112E-07
```

I would like to format the column so that they have a common exponent, say E-06 like so:

```
11.23E-06
4.567E-06
8910 E-06
0.112E-06
```

The number of decimal places don't have to be the same. I'm more interested in scaling the numbers to the same exponent/ power. How can I achieve that? I am using Microsoft Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved the issue. I used the custom `###0.0E-12` format, where the # mean the integer part of the number can be any width. This would be particularly useful if you want to format numbers in a column to use a particular unit, for example micro-watts (x 10E-3), micrometre (x 10E-6) etc, etc.